# Read data in custom class from kafka in Spark streaming

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka

I am using kafka-2.3.0 along with Spark-2.4.3 streaming. So, I am trying to deserialize the data in my custom UserData class using the following method. To deserialize I have created the `UserDataDeserializer` class.

```
case class UserData(Category: String, Action: String .....)

class UserDataDeserializer extends Deserializer[UserData]{

override def deserialize(topic:String,bytes: Array[Byte]) = {
    val byteIn = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes)
    val objIn = new ObjectInputStream(byteIn)
    val obj = objIn.readObject().asInstanceOf[UserData]
    byteIn.close()
    objIn.close()
    obj
}

override def close():Unit = {

}

override def configure(configs: util.Map[String, _], isKey: Boolean): Unit = {

}
}
```

To consume it in Spark-Streaming I am using the following code

```
val kafkaParams = Map[String, Object](
       "bootstrap.servers" -> "localnosql1:9092,localnosql2:9092",
       "key.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
       "value.deserializer" -> classOf[UserDataDeserializer],
       "group.id" -> "streaming-group",
       "auto.offset.reset" -> "earliest",  // it could be earliest
       "auto.commit.interval.ms" -> "500",
       "enable.auto.commit" -> (true: java.lang.Boolean)
)
val topics = Array("USERDATA")
val stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String]( ssc, PreferConsistent, Subscribe[String, String](topics, kafkaParams))
```

But I am getting the following error :

**Error:**

```
 org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka consumer
      at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:702)
      at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:557)
      at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:540)
      at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.Subscribe.onStart(ConsumerStrategy.scala:84)
      at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.DirectKafkaInputDStream.consumer(DirectKafkaInputDStream.scala:70)
      at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.DirectKafkaInputDStream.start(DirectKafkaInputDStream.scala:240)
      at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph$$anonfun$start$7.apply(DStreamGraph.scala:54)
      at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph$$anonfun$start$7.apply(DStreamGraph.scala:54)
      at scala.collection.parallel.mutable.ParArray$ParArrayIterator.foreach_quick(ParArray.scala:143)
      at scala.collection.parallel.mutable.ParArray$ParArrayIterator.foreach(ParArray.scala:136)
      at scala.collection.parallel.ParIterableLike$Foreach.leaf(ParIterableLike.scala:972)
      at scala.collection.parallel.Task$$anonfun$tryLeaf$1.apply$mcV$sp(Tasks.scala:49)
      at scala.collection.parallel.Task$$anonfun$tryLeaf$1.apply(Tasks.scala:48)
      at scala.collection.parallel.Task$$anonfun$tryLeaf$1.apply(Tasks.scala:48)
      at scala.collection.parallel.Task$class.tryLeaf(Tasks.scala:51)
      at scala.collection.parallel.ParIterableLike$Foreach.tryLeaf(ParIterableLike.scala:969)
      at scala.collection.parallel.AdaptiveWorkStealingTasks$WrappedTask$class.compute(Tasks.scala:152)
      at scala.collection.parallel.AdaptiveWorkStealingForkJoinTasks$WrappedTask.compute(Tasks.scala:443)
      at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.RecursiveAction.exec(RecursiveAction.java:160)
      at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
      at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
      at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
      at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
      at ... run in separate thread using org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils ... ()
      at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.liftedTree1$1(StreamingContext.scala:578)
      at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.start(StreamingContext.scala:572)
      ... 71 elided
    Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Could not instantiate class UserDataDeserializer Does it have a public no-argument constructor?
```

Answer (score 0):

Whilst you created your own UserDataDeserializer, it's complaining about EventDataDeserializer ( which seems to not have a no argument constructor btw), that you specified in your spark streaming :       "value.deserializer" -> classOf[EventDataDeserializer]

Is it a clue for you ? Shouldn't you use your UserDataDeserializer?

Yannick

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. I have corrected the question.

Comment: Chances are you're using a class that should have a no argument constructor, but you're not actually. From your class UserDataDeserializer  above, it has normally a no-arg constructor, so this is weird. Are you sure you did run it using this class ?